# Problem with how pop() and enumerate() interact

Tags: python-3.x, stack, enumerate

When I use List.pop inside a for loop that uses enumerate, the process terminates before getting to the end of the list. How do I get around having pop cut short the process?

I've checked that if I write the loop using pop but without enumerate, then it works as expected. Likewise, if I remove pop and use enumerate to do something else, it also works as expected.

Here is the code:

```
x=[0,2,4,6,8,10] 
for i in enumerate(x):
x.pop(0)
print(x)
```

I expect to have the following printed:

```
[2,4,6,8,10]
[4,6,8,10]
[6,8,10]
[8,10]
[10]
[]
```

Instead, I receive

```
[2,4,6,8,10]
[4,6,8,10]
[6,8,10]
```

If I run it again then I receive

```
[8,10]
[10]
```

and if I run it again I receive

```
[]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `range`

**Ex:**

```
x=[0,2,4,6,8,10] 
for i in range(len(x)):
    x.pop(0)
    print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
[4, 6, 8, 10]
[6, 8, 10]
[8, 10]
[10]
[]
```

**Note:** Modifying a list while iterating it is not good practice.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you explain why len(x) isn't also problematic sense x is getting modified? I'm Ok with using the version you suggest, but I'd like to understand why the enumerate version doesn't work.